# How do I set up a Django user for use in a Selenium test case with the setUp method?

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I am working to create Selenium unit tests for my code. I have a simple login form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="f00b4r">
        
    <div id="div_id_username" class="form-group"> 
        <label for="id_username" class="requiredField">Callsign
            <spanclass="asteriskField">*</span> 
        </label> 
        <div> 
            <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" maxlength="150" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_username"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="div_id_password" class="form-group"> 
        <label for="id_password" class="requiredField">Password
            <span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
        </label> 
        <div> 
            <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_password"> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

And this is the test case:

```
class TestLoginFormFirefox(LiveServerTestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.good_user = User.objects.create_user(username="unittest", password="this_is_unit")

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

def test_index_login_success(self):
    """
    When a user successfully logs in, a link to their profile should appear in the navbar
    """
    self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login')
    username_field = self.driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='id_username')
    password_field = self.driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='id_password')
    username_field.send_keys('unittest')
    password_field.send_keys("this_is_unit")
    login_button = self.driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="btn-primary")
    login_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    # needs time to render
    sleep(3)
    id_profile_link = self.driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='id_profile_link').text
    assert id_profile_link == 'unittest'
```

The test is simple: if the user specified in the unittest setUp method is able to successfully log in, assert that the user's username is a part of a link in the next page.

The rub here is that the setUp method creates the user object, but the login fails. This persisted until I made a user in the project's database with the same username and password through createsuperuser. Is there any way to create a valid test user for this flow without having to make it beforehand using createsuperuser to have it in the project's `auth_user` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run tests using Django's test framework (like using `LiveServerTestCase`), django sets up a separate test database for the duration of the tests.
This test database is independent of your project's main database.

The `setUp` method in your test class correctly creates a user in this test database, but if your Selenium test is running against your main application (which is using your project's main database), it won't have access to the user created in the test database. That's why your login attempts fail until you create a user manually in the main database.

A few options:

- Use Django's Test Server: The URL in your test method `self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login')` should point to the test server, which usually runs on a different port. Django's `LiveServerTestCase` provides a `live_server_url` attribute, which gives you the URL of the test server.

  ```
  self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/login')
  ```
- Create a User in Your Test Setup and use it